# asp.net swashbucle/swagger not showing post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have configured swashbucle in my asp.net project and is working ok but one problem. It does not show the info for one method i.e. POST.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(CRUD_Request_Response))]
[HttpPost]
public CRUD_Request_Response Post(CRUD_Request_Response _theCRUD)
{
    return ProcessCRUD(theCRUD);
}

[ResponseType(typeof(CRUD_Request_Response))]
[HttpPut]
public CRUD_Request_Response Put(CRUD_Request_Response _theCRUD)
{
    return ProcessCRUD(theCRUD);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post the entire code for that controller, also include the code for your model(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2 methods have the same signature. Swashbuckle gets confused about the difference between the two and does not show eather.